# Compilation errors in a PLSQL query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm querying data from a table with a stored function but I don't get it working.

Can anyone help me?

I can't get the right result I want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION diff (empnoinput1 emp.empno%TYPE, empnoinput2 emp.empno%TYPE) RETURN VARCHAR IS
    ename1 emp.ename%TYPE;
    ename2 emp.ename%TYPE;
    date1 DATE;
    date2 DATE;
    date_diff NUMBER;
    return_value VARCHAR;

BEGIN
    SELECT ename INTO ename1 FROM emp WHERE empno = empnoinput1;
    SELECT ename INTO ename2 FROM emp WHERE empno = empnoinput2;
    SELECT hiredate INTO date1 FROM emp WHERE empno = empnoinput1;
    SELECT hiredate INTO date2 FROM emp WHERE empno = empnoinput2;
    IF date1 < date2 THEN
        date_diff := date2 - date1;
        return_value := ename1 || ' ' || date_diff || ' Tage vor ' || ename2;
    ELSE
        date_diff := date1 - date2;
        return_value := ename2 || ' ' || date_diff || ' Tage vor ' || ename1;
    END IF;
    RETURN '1 mistake';
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN 'big mistake';
END diff;
/

SELECT diff(7369, 7499) FROM dual;
```

The error is:

```
LINE/COL ERROR 
-------- ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
1/87 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following: 
                . @ % ; is authid as cluster order using external 
                character deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate result_cache
```

Comment: Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SELECT diff(7369, 7499) FROM dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06575: Package or function DIFF is in an invalid state

Comment: actually you are not returning the 'return_value' anywhere, so why are you using it???

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have only declared your variable `return_value` as `VARCHAR`. They need to be VARCHAR(n) where n is between 1 and 32767.

Use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Eg:

```
return_value VARCHAR2(50);
```

Comment: `RETURN VARCHAR2(50) IS`
and
`return_value VARCHAR2(50);`

That's what I have changed but still the same problem.

Comment: Mention it in your declaration part and try.

Comment: `return_value VARCHAR2(50);` is in the declaration part

Comment: still the same.

`Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SELECT diff(7369, 7499) FROM dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06575: Package or function DIFF is in an invalid state `

Comment: @max.mustermann1: type `show errors function diff`.  That will give you some more helpful messages.

Comment: The error looks like your function is in invalid state. Please try to compile your function and let me know the error you are getting.

Comment: `LINE/COL ERROR                                                                  
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------      
1/87     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the        
         following:                                                             
         . @ % ; is authid as cluster order using external character            
         deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate                      
         result_cache                                                           `

Comment: Remove the `(50)` from `RETURN VARCHAR2(50) IS`, it's just `RETURN VARCHAR2 IS`